# IXamlType interface implementation - weird behavior

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The **IXamlType** interface is defined as follows:

```
[Guid(0x7920eab1, 0xa2e5, 0x479a, 0xbd, 80, 0x6c, 0xef, 60, 11, 0x49, 0x70), Version(0x6020000), WebHostHidden]
public interface IXamlType
{
    // Methods
    object ActivateInstance();
    void AddToMap([In] object instance, [In] object key, [In] object value);
    void AddToVector([In] object instance, [In] object value);
    object CreateFromString([In] string value);
    IXamlMember GetMember([In] string name);
    void RunInitializer();

    // Properties
    IXamlType BaseType { get; }
    IXamlMember ContentProperty { get; }
    string FullName { get; }
    bool IsArray { get; }
    bool IsBindable { get; }
    bool IsCollection { get; }
    bool IsConstructible { get; }
    bool IsDictionary { get; }
    bool IsMarkupExtension { get; }
    IXamlType ItemType { get; }
    IXamlType KeyType { get; }
    TypeName UnderlyingType { get; }
}
```

When a Metro Application is compiled a **XamlTypeInfo.g.cs** is generated which contains an implementation of this interface as follows:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", "4.0.0.0")]    
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
internal class XamlSystemBaseType : IXamlType
{
    string _fullName;
    Type _underlyingType;

    public XamlSystemBaseType(string fullName, Type underlyingType)
    {
        _fullName = fullName;
        _underlyingType = underlyingType;
    }

    public string FullName { get { return _fullName; } }

    public Type UnderlyingType
    {
        get
        {
            return _underlyingType;
        }
    }

    virtual public IXamlType BaseType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public IXamlMember ContentProperty { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public IXamlMember GetMember(string name) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual public bool IsArray { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public bool IsCollection { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public bool IsConstructible { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public bool IsDictionary { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public bool IsMarkupExtension { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public bool IsBindable { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public IXamlType ItemType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public IXamlType KeyType { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    virtual public object ActivateInstance() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual public void AddToMap(object instance, object key, object item)  { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual public void AddToVector(object instance, object item)  { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual public void RunInitializer()   { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual public object CreateFromString(String input)   { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

---

The weird thing is that some of the interface implementations are not consistent. If you try to compile this implementation in a stand-alone VS project, it gives the following error as expected:

**error CS0738: 'ConsoleApplication28.XamlSystemBaseType' does not implement interface member 'ConsoleApplication28.IXamlType.UnderlyingType'. 'ConsoleApplication28.XamlSystemBaseType.UnderlyingType' cannot implement 'ConsoleApplication28.IXamlType.UnderlyingType' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ConsoleApplication28.TypeName'.**

---

My question is how does the .g.cs compile - I confirmed by opening the compiled assembly in Reflector - it also showed the same implementation which has mis-matching signature types for some properties/methods.

**Update:**

To confirm what I saw, I used Reflector and saw following:

The IXamlType.UnderlyingType (from assembly Windows, Version=255.255.255.255) is defined as:

```
TypeName UnderlyingType { get; }
```

The XamlSystemBaseType found in any Metro app defines UnderlyingType as:

```
   public Type UnderlyingType { get; }
```

Given the above, I don't understand how it works!

**Update #2**

OK - When you open the Windows.winmd file in Reflector, you see:

```
TypeName UnderlyingType { get; }
```

However, if in Visual Studio you do:

Place cursor on **IXamlType** of following line:

internal class XamlSystemBaseType : IXamlType

Then **Press F12,** the auto-generated definition file that opens has:

```
    public Type UnderlyingType { get; }
```

So something is definitely happening under the scenes which I am not aware of!

Documentation of what (if??) some types are auto-mapped to other types and rules/attributes corresponding to this would be of much help!

Comment: The only thing I can see you proving is that the Reflector tool you are using does not work well with WinMD. The whole projection thing is probably using a lot of hacks to be able to work, so I am even surprised Reflector is able to make any sense of it at all. Is there any reason you are checking this?

Comment: The thing has boiled down to simply this: the winmd file (as Reflector shows it) contains something else, but VS shows something else. Either one of them is wrong (I doubt this) or some voodoo (mapping/projection/etc) is going on - if this is the case, I am looking for documentation on this voodoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this happens because of something called "projected types", however I have not been able to find any formal documentation on this. I have started another question for this here:

[WinRT Projected types documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679515/winrt-projected-types-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that the interface definition you found declares the UnderlyingType property as

```
TypeName UnderlyingType { get; }
```

While the generated base implementation defines it as:

```
public Type UnderlyingType ...
```

Well, I opened XamlTypeInfo.g.cs in VS and navigated to the definition of IXamlType interface and it actually defines it as

```
Type UnderlyingType { get; }
```

Seems like the interface definition you found is not valid. Looking at the documentation of the [UnderlyingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.ixamltype.underlyingtype.aspx) property it says the type of that property is Type in C#, but TypeName in C++ - which is possibly where your discrepancy somehow came from.

The bigger question is - why would you try to compile it in a Console application? Console apps do not use WinRT.

Comment: I used a Console app, simply to confirm my suspicion that it should not compile at all!